# Is there a word or phrase for the moment while taking a picture when there are no tourists (e.g unwanted distractions) in your viewfinder?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This came up during a trip and was thinking there must be a word to capture the moment while taking a picture and waiting for tourists to move out of your perfectly framed building/fountain/status shot.

Comment: Nothing special, just something like _unobstructed view_ or _clear view_.

Comment: Do you mean the time spent waiting or the time during which there's an opportunity? Are you aware of [Photography.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You can remove the tourists from your photos: http://i.imgur.com/Gkn1ngK.jpg

Comment: It's called a "photosecond", which is an indeterminate fraction of a nanosecond.

Answer (score 0):

If it's one of those touristic attractions where there are crowds all the time, you might call it a "magic moment", or "a lucky strike".

Answer (score 0):

"golden opportunity"
"narrow window"

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for idioms or cliches that would convey the feeling of seeing something, a site, thing or place, in a rare form, that is, without the tourists who usually haunt the site, thing or place.

`"Rare Glimpse"`

### Examples

"We got a **rare glimpse** of the Taj Mahal when no one else was there!"

"In my photo you get a **rare glimplse** of Waikiki beach with no tourists."